# Change order of groups in weighted geom_density

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

Given the following example I would like to rearrange the densities by size, so that the biggest area (the group of *"ideal"*) is in the back and the smallest area (the group of *"fair"*) is in the front. This would facilitate the interpretation especially if the areas vary considerably in size.

```
ggplot(diamonds, aes(depth, fill = cut, colour = cut, weight=price)) +
  geom_density(alpha = 0.5) +
  xlim(55, 70)
```

[image]

Comment: What's the biggest? By area or peak height?

Comment: You can do this by rearranging factor levels but then the key (legend) will also be changed.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Biggest means "by area" which makes only sense if the data is weighted. I edited the question above. It does not matter if the legend changes. So the rearrangement of the factor levels would be done according to the group sums in price?

Comment: You prly want to rearrange the factor levels like `d <- diamonds;d$cut <- factor(d$cut, levels=names(sort(table(d$cut), de = T))); ggplot(d, aes(depth, fill = cut, colour = cut, weight=price)) +geom_density(alpha = 0.5)`.

Comment: this worked for me. you might consider posting it as an answer.